# BufferTime with leading option

Tags: rxjs

I have some events that I'd like to buffer but I'd like to buffer only after the first element.

```
[------bufferTime------]

Input over time:
[1, 2, 3, -------------|---4, 5, 6 ----------------]


Output over time:
[1]-----------------[2,3]---[4]------------------[5,6]
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got really good answers that enlightened my view of the problem and made me come up with the real thing that I was needing, that was something like this:

```js
function getLeadingBufferSubject (bufferTimeArg) {
    const source = new Subject()
    const result = new Subject()

    let didOutputLeading = false

    const buffered$ = source
        .pipe(bufferTime(bufferTimeArg))
        .pipe(filter(ar => ar.length > 0))
        .pipe(map(ar => [...new Set(ar)]))

    buffered$.subscribe(v => {
        didOutputLeading = false
        const slicedArray = v.slice(1)

        // emits buffered values (except the first)  and set flag to false
        if (.length > 0) result.next(v.slice(1))
    })

    // emits first value if buffer is empty
    source.subscribe(v => {
        if (!didOutputLeading) {
            didOutputLeading = true
             result.next(v)
        }
    })

    // call .next(value) on "source"
    // subscribe for results on "result"
    return {
        source,
        result
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to offer another solution, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63994576/8578281

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be solved by dividing your stream into two, firstValue$ and afterFirstValue$, and then merging them.

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { take, skip, bufferTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

firstValue$ = source$.pipe(
  take(1)
);

afterFirstValue$ = source$.pipe(
  skip(1),
  bufferTime(5000)
);

merge(firstValue$, afterFirstValue$)
  .subscribe(result => {
    // Do something
  });
```

---

### Answer to follow up question concerning subject

So I have done it so that the original source is a subject here. It is not exactly how you described it, but I think maybe this is what you want.

```
  import { merge, Subject } from 'rxjs';
  import { take, skip, bufferTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
  import { Source } from 'webpack-sources';

  ...

  source$ = new Subject();

  firstValue$ = source$.pipe(
    take(1)
  );

  afterFirstValue$ = source$.pipe(
    skip(1),
    bufferTime(5000)
  );

  merge(firstValue$, afterFirstValue$)
    .subscribe(result => {
      // Do something
    });

  source$.next(1);
  source$.next(1);
  source$.next(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan & @martin, I understood both approach. As I'm kinda new to Rx I'm sticking with Dan's for now, but will try the other out :) 

Now I'm having some troubles getting it into my code, can you help me out?

I need the merge of those methods to be a Subject, as shown on this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/duj4htfa/

How can I turn that Observable (from merge) to a Subject?

Comment: @melloc So I added an answer to this as well, see above. Please tell me if this was not what you wanted. Also, I see in your fiddle that you are using the old syntax for a lot of the RxJS stuff. For example "buffered$.skip(1)" is "buffered$.pipe(skip(1))" with the new syntax, and "new Rx.Subject()" is " new Subject()".

Comment: Cool! Thanks SnorreDan, but take(1) will only work once, right? I wanted it to work on every event burst, maybe I must stick with @martin option?

tested on: https://codesandbox.io/s/1zl3q667ml

Comment: Yes, the take(1) makes it so that it only takes in 1 event. But then we have afterFirstValue$ that takes in all the other events. Then we merge them together, so we will get every event in the subscribe after the merge.

Comment: I think I am probably misunderstanding you somewhere @melloc

Comment: Try to read my comment above and look at the updated example on the description.
Not sure if I can do this with Rx, maybe I'll write my own function

Comment: I think you can achieve this as well. Window, windowCount or windowTime operators could be helpful. Exactly how to do it depends on how you select what element is the first element before each buffer. Does it depend on time, is it always first 1 and then 2 values, or is there some special value coming through that say that this is the first value?

Comment: Nope,  the algorithm would be something like this:  new [event]: if addToBuffer == false emit output (take 1), addToBuffer= false, else add to buffer, the buffer's subscriber would have to assign `false` to the `addToBuffer` flag

Not sure if that'll be understandable, haha I'll try to write this on a jsfiddle

Comment: I think I got it to work, check this out @SnorreDan: https://codesandbox.io/s/1r8jzwm764

Answer (score 2):

You can use `multicast` to split the stream into two and just pass the first value through.

```
import { concat, Subject } from “rxjs”;
import { multicast, take, bufferCount } from “rxjs/operators”;

source.pipe(
  multicast(
    new Subject(),
    s => concat(
      s.pipe(take(1)),
      s.pipe(bufferCount(X)),
    )
  ),
);
```

Comment: Wow, thats nice! For my simple mind though I found Dan's answer to be easier to grasp. Still this one is sexier :)

Comment: I can't argue with that @Kos

Comment: Only the "1" is emitted by itself, this does not work for the "4", see https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-goodall-4r50e?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after playing around with it, I found this additional solution:

```js
source$.pipe(
  buffer(source$.pipe(
    throttleTime(bufferTime, asyncScheduler, {leading: true, trailing: true}),
    delay(10) // <-- This here bugs me like crazy though!
  )
)
```

Because `throttle` already features a `leading` option, you can just use it to trigger buffer emits manually.

I would really like to get rid of that `delay` here though. This is necessary because the inner observable is triggered first causing the buffer to emit prematurely.

Comment: I think you could use asapScheduler and delay(0). (delay could be either before or after the throttleTime).
At some point you have to delay the notifier, I don't see other option.