# RxJS: why is inner observable firing first?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using RxJS 6 and I have the following [example problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404098/buffertime-with-leading-option):

We want to buffer elements for a specified `bufferTime` but if nothing happend for some amount of time greater than `bufferTime` we want the first element to fire immediately.

Sequence:

```
[------bufferTime------]

Input over time:
[1, 2, 3, -------------|---4, 5, 6 ----------------]


Output over time:
[1]-----------------[2,3]---[4]------------------[5,6]
```

This is the code that gets me there:

```js
source$.pipe(
  buffer(source$.pipe(
    throttleTime(bufferTime, asyncScheduler, {leading: true, trailing: true}),
    delay(10) // <-- This here bugs me like crazy though!
  )
)
```

My question is about the `delay` operator. When I omit it, the buffer fires with an empty list because the `$source.pipe(throttleTime(...))` is faster than the buffer step.

Without `delay`

```
[------bufferTime------]

Input over time:
[1, 2, 3, -------------|---4, 5, 6 ----------------]


Output over time:
[]------------------[1,2,3]--[]------------------[4,5,6]
```

Is there any way to get rid of the `delay`?

Comment: why you using `throttleTime` to buffer your elements ?

Comment: Because `throttleTime` has the `leading` and `trailing` options built in and that's pretty much the behavior I want. If I only use `bufferTime` I don't get the immediate response from the first item, i.e. the leading element. I am open to other ideas to solve the problem though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the order in which the observers subscribe to a stream is preserved when a new value comes: The first that subscribed will receive the value first, then the next one, and so on.

In [v6](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/src/internal/operators/buffer.ts#L59), `buffer` will first subscribe to the inner stream, which will subscribe to `source$` first, and then it (buffer) will subscribe to `source$` in second place. To clarify, when a new value comes in, the first one to receive the new value will be the inner observable, because it subscribed to the source before `buffer` did.

In [v7](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/buffer.ts#L60) that's swapped out, so it should work without any extra work

As a cleaner solution for v6, there's an operator that can help you: `subscribeOn`. With this you can specify a scheduler to use when subscribing to the operator, in your case by using a micro-task with `asapScheduler` it should work:

```js
source$.pipe(
  buffer(source$.pipe(
    subscribeOn(asapScheduler),
    throttleTime(bufferTime, asyncScheduler, {leading: true, trailing: true}),
  )
)
```

This way the inner subscription to source will be postponed *after* the buffer has subscribed to it.

Note that if you're creating a custom operator with this implementation, you might want to multicast the source$ with the overload `publish(multicasted$ => ...)`, otherwise this snippet will make 2 subscriptions to `source$` (potentially sending a request twice?)

Comment: This is better than my answer in terms of less code and more information, it was even interesting for me, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so thoroughly, that's exactly what I needed. And thanks for the extra mile with the links to the relevant source code!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, you can play with it in the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/exhaust-map-buffer-time?file=index.ts):

```
const source$: Observable<string> = interval(300).pipe(
  map(x => "a" + x),
  share()
);

source$.pipe(
  exhaustMap(value => {
    return concat(
      of([value]),
      source$.pipe(
        bufferTime(1000),
        take(1)
      )
    );
  })
).subscribe(x => console.log(x, new Date()));
```

Output is:

`["a0"] 2020-09-21T14:39:49.895Z`

`["a1", "a2", "a3"] 2020-09-21T14:39:50.899Z`

`["a4"] 2020-09-21T14:39:51.096Z`

`["a5", "a6", "a7"] 2020-09-21T14:40:30.967Z`